# how can i send a skype message from My android app?

Tags: android, android-intent, skype, skype4com

I tried to make an intent like calling intent

```
            Intent skype = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
        skype.setData(Uri.parse("skype:" + "user_name" + "?message=ddd"));
        startActivity(skype);
```

and it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with official Android SDK, as well as Skype URI's is that they not allow to share predefined message. You can just open chat with list of users (or empty to create a new one). If you want to explicity share some text with Skype you can try to use system Intents with Skype package name (remember to check if this package name is installed, otherwise startActivity call will crash your app):

```
val SKYPE_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.skype.raider"

fun shareSkype(context: Context, message: String) {
    if (!isAppInstalled(context, SKYPE_PACKAGE_NAME)) {
        openAppInGooglePlay(context, SKYPE_PACKAGE_NAME)
        return
    }
    val intent = context.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(SKYPE_PACKAGE_NAME)
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message)
    intent.type = "text/plain"
    context.startActivity(intent)
}

fun isAppInstalled(context: Context, packageName: String): Boolean {
    val packageManager = context.packageManager
    try {
        packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES)
    } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If Skype or other Android messaging applications do not have publicly available Intents, it will not be possible to do so until they are available.

You could however try to find a proxy service that skype uses to call within your application as a means to send messages.

http://developer.skype.com/skype-uris/reference#uriChats

Notice:

**Caveats:**

The optional topic argument applies to multi-chats only.

Special characters in the topic argument value—specifically whitespace—must be escaped.

Mac OS X: ignores any topic argument.

iOS: not supported.

Android: recognizes the initial participant only; multi-chats are not supported.

**Android Docs - http://developer.skype.com/skype-uris/skype-uri-tutorial-android**

```
/**
 * Initiate the actions encoded in the specified URI.
 */
public void initiateSkypeUri(Context myContext, String mySkypeUri) {

  // Make sure the Skype for Android client is installed
  if (!isSkypeClientInstalled(myContext)) {
    goToMarket(myContext);
    return;
  }

  // Create the Intent from our Skype URI
  Uri skypeUri = Uri.parse(mySkypeUri);
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, skypeUri);

  // Restrict the Intent to being handled by the Skype for Android client only
  myIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.skype.raider", "com.skype.raider.Main"));
  myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

  // Initiate the Intent. It should never fail since we've already established the
  // presence of its handler (although there is an extremely minute window where that
  // handler can go away...)
  myContext.startActivity(myIntent);

  return;
}
```

Comment: Updated Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn745882.aspx for API reference

Comment: not relevant answer! Your code and link it's about to open a chat NOT to send a text message!

Comment: @Choletski The code and [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745884.aspx) originally showed how you might initiate any Skype URI. Since `mySkypeUri` is ambiguous in the code above, it can mean many actions. The [updated Skype URI API reference link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745882.aspx) posted in a previous comment goes over the respective items, which one includes: "Sending instant messages to an individual or establishing a group multichat". Which was possible at the time of writing the answer.